# Jquery .load() callback function timing.

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, jquery-callback, jquery-load

I am trying to load an image using .load() then based on the size of that image manipulate it to fit into a certain area. The issue I'm having is that when my callback function runs the image is not actually loaded and I cannot get the height and width. This is how my code looks.

```
foo.load("/loadimage/"+id, function(){editImage(foo)});

function editImage(foo){
  var $fooImg = foo.find(img);
  var imgHeight = $fooImg.height();
  var imgWidth = $fooImg.width();
}
```

$fooImg height and width both return 0 when this runs though. I checked the network status of the request in chrome and it says that it is "pending".

I want to run this right after the image is loaded then if the image it taller then wide I want to set CSS height to 100% and vise versa for width.

Comment: this might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4877762/getting-width-and-height-of-image-after-jquery-load

Comment: Note that the linked question involved the old load-event version of .load, not the ajax load. The solutions however are still relevant.